# Data not showing in QGIS when connecting to Oracle

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, extents, oracle-spatial

I have an Oracle XE 11g spatial database that is connected to a web map. All the layers of the web map are stored in the database and they work just fine. I sometime need to edit some of the layers in the web map and for this task I use QGIS but the problem is that when I try to add the Oracle tables in QGIS nothing shown on the screen, although the tables have spatial indexes!

Has anyone faced a smimilar problem in QGIS?

Comment: Do they also have lines in the user_sdo_geom_metadata table?